# React Router: Issue with Component Rendering Based on Routes

Tags: reactjs

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at handleParseError (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:449:10)
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:481:5
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:342:12
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10) 
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10) 
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\React Project\demoproject\demo\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

how to resolve this

I used this :
npm install react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it using one of the following.

1. Downgrade to Node v16.

   You can use nvm for this.
2. Enable legacy OpenSSL provider

   ```
   export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
   ```
3. Update OpenSSL

   ```
   brew update
   brew upgrade openssl
   ```